# iOS 6 Xcode 4.5 unsupported architecture armv7s

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, armv7

When trying to archive an app for an Ad Hoc release, I am getting the following warning:

`iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): armv7s (-19031)`

I am really not sure why this is happening for two reasons:

- The only non-foundation framework I am using is the Facebook SDK, which is the latest version
- I successfully archived the app last week and the only things that have changed since then are purely coding changes.

Also, I have tried archiving with and without an iPhone 5 plugged in, and I receive the error both ways.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the application architecture selected in build settings?

Comment: Weird. I get the same errors today in TWO apps (both v1.1 updates) that were previously released including armv7 AND armv7s...

Comment: Make sure you have chosen same Base SDK options on Project and Target Architecture settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick fix is

Remove armv7s from

> Project -> Build Settings -> Architecures

Updated ::

Now change Build Active Architecture in Build Settings to No to Yes. 
But even this is not a pure solution to this problem.

Comment: but not actually a fix. I'm having the same problem as above, and would like to fully support the iPhone5.

Comment: Then you would need to build all your libraries with armv7s, also get latest third party libraries like AdMob, Urban Airship etc and you will not have to do these quick fixes

Comment: Xcode 4.5.2 seems to have updated the libraries so might be worth trying again after updating to Xcode 4.5.2

Comment: Yes, that turned out to be the problem. Xcode 4.5.1 had a temporary bug with validation, which seems to have been triggered on Apple's servers (Apple bug id 12240727). 4.5.2 is fine.

Answer (score 7):

I could archive and validate my projects by changing status of 'Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only' from 'No' to 'Yes'.

Comment: It would essentially be the same as removing armv7s from "Architectures" provided that the architecture that goes into the archive is armv7 and not armv7s.

Answer (score 5):

Same problem here today when submit my app (update) to appstore.

I clearly remember that its last version was submitted with both armv7 and armv7s set and succeeded, but now Organizer told me :

"iPhone/iPod Touch : application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): armv7s"

to remove armv7s is simple, but my app is Universal, will the armv7s-removed app run on all iOS devices (iPhone 5 for example)? when should i build with aremv7s?

Comment: Same effect over here... someone over in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899451/iphone-ipod-touch-application-executable-contains-unsupported-architectures?lq=1 says you won't get the iPhone5's full performance, but your app will run on it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Same issues here, app passed validation before, but after a quick code change, no go. Could this possibly have something to do with ipods? Seems to be a recent issue, as of yesterday.

Comment: I can confirm this. An app that was previously submitting updates fine is now failing validation for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the same result as 21k.  I submitted a binary with both `armv7` and `armv7s` to the App Store last week, and it passed validation as well as the review.  Now I tried submitting an update to the same app with the exact same project settings (other than the usual version number bump), and it fails validation.

In fact, I try validating the archived app from last week and now get the same error.  So something must have changed on the App Store's side.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project ---> Build Settings and scroll down to the Architecture setting.

You will probably see the value $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) listed under Architecture.

If so, double-click $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT), select it, and click the minus button to get rid of it. Then click the plus button and write armv7 and press Enter.

You have now removed armv7s, which was unsupported. Try it again and things should be good.

Answer (score -1):

Removes armv7s architecture from menu Build settings > Architectures. At that point must appear valid architectural amrv7s and amrv7. Removes only finished in s. If the menu doesn't appears, notice that it is set to "All" and "Combined" in the search bar.