# iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): armv7s (-19031)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS 6 Xcode 4.5 unsupported architecture armv7s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832232/ios-6-xcode-4-5-unsupported-architecture-armv7s)

I am planning to submit this update for the iPhone 5.

When I try to create an archive, I get the following warning:

```
iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): armv7s (-19031)
```

How can I resolve this ? What should I do in order to support iPhone 5 ?

Note:

I am using the following frameworks:

1. Core Data
2. Quartz Core
3. AVFoundation
4. UIKit
5. Foundation
6. Core Graphics
7. SenTestingKit

Comment: Thanks Till, after removing armv7s would it support iPhone 5. Pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SenTestingKit` does not support `armv7s` Either remove `armv7s` from the architectures or remove the use of the SenTestingKit until they update for `armv7s`.

**EDIT**: Removing `armv7s` will still allow your application to run on the iPhone 5, however you will not get the full performance of the `armv7s` processor.

Comment: I have removed armv7s and added armv7 under Project > Build Settings > Architectures. Now will the app support iPhone 5 ?

Comment: Yes, that is how you remove armv7s. Yes your app will run on iPhone 5 without `armv7s`. The `armv7s` build will just make it run faster and be best performance on the iphone 5 processor. Is there a detail error message after that exit code? Also delete your `Derived Data` folder and run a `clean` under the product menu.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation Bot, I suppose I made a blunder while adding armv7, I forgot to remove armv7s. That caused the error, now it is fine. Let me see if I can remove SenTestingKit and if it works with armv7s. If yes then thats a better option bcuz I don't need test cases  when the app is in release mode / gone live. wud need it only I am developing / debugging

Comment: I retained armv7s and removed SenTestingKit framework from the targets . I just selected SenTestingKit and went to the inspector and unchecked under Target Membership. But it seems to throw the same warning 19031 as in the original post. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @user1046037 check your linked binaries and remove it from there. Also don't forget to delete your `derived data` folder and run a `clean`

Comment: Thanks Bot, I tried that but didn't work. So i created a new dummy project without testcases (without SenTestingKit). The new project contains only UIKit, Foundation and CoreGraphics. And still the new project had the same warning. So I suppose one or more of these libraries don't support armv7s

Comment: Can you pls update your answer to include that removing armv7s "will run on iPhone 5 without armv7s. The armv7s build will just make it run faster and be best performance on the iphone 5 processor". So that it can benefit others viewing this. I suppose for now, thats the best possible solution. So I can mark that as answered. Let me know if i am still missing a point regarding one of the 3 basic libraries (UIKit, Foundation and CoreGraphics) not supporting armv7s

Comment: @user1046037 those libraries support armv7s. What version of xcode do you have and what version of the sdk?

Comment: I am using Xcode Version 4.5.1 (4G1004) on Mac OS X 10.8.2