# armv7s Issue while validating

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, armv7

[image]

So,while validating my application, I got this issue. Looked it up alot on google, and I just can't seem to find how to solve it. I have all SDK's updated, and the newest version of XCODE.  I've tested the app on a IRL iPhone 4, and the iPhone Simulator. Quick fix/Info needed to fix this issue?

Comment: It looks like a dupe of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832232/ios-6-xcode-4-5-unsupported-architecture-armv7s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this to yes. Great success.

[image]

Comment: That will essentially remove support for armv7s. Your app will still run on the iPhone 5, however you will not get the full performance of the armv7s processor.

Comment: This question as a better solution, in my opinion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150116/when-should-i-build-app-with-armv7s-support

Comment: i'll update that later then. Not a resource heavy app at all tho, so should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In valid architectures, $VALID_ARCHS, please set armv7 and armv7s in build settings. It's an issue with latest XCode that, by default it does not support armv7. And armv7 is required for iPhon4,4s since they are having A5 processor, whereas iPhon5 is having A7 processor.

For finding out difference in these processors, plz find details in following link:

http://www.anandtech.com/show/6292/iphone-5-a6-not-a15-custom-core