# What happens when you compile with Standard Architectures (armv7, armv7s)?

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have an SDK that I'm trying to compile and I was wondering what happens when I choose the Standard Architectures (armv7, armv7s) option under "Architectures"?

It is my understanding that the armv7 instruction set can run on devices that support armv7s as well but not the other way around.  So when I compile with this option is the compiler outputting a binary with two SDKs, each using a different instruction set or just one with armv7?

I'm confused and not sure if I'm thinking about this correctly.

Comment: you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569339/what-is-armv7s and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150116/when-should-i-build-app-with-armv7s-support

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you specify both armv7 and armv7s, it builds a "fat binary" containing two sets of object code, one targeted for armv7 and the other for armv7s. When the app is installed on a phone, the installer uses the correct object code for the device it is installed on.

You *could* specify just "armv7" and, you are correct, the generated object code will run on both an armv7 and an armv7s. However, it will run slower on the armv7s than a binary containing both sets of code.

In general, unless you have a specific reason for not doing it, stick with "Standard Architecture", since that provides the best support for the currently supported iOS devices.

Comment: So the only benefit I would get from compiling just armv7 would be my binary would be smaller but then it would run slower on armv7s processors?

Comment: That's basically correct. The binary would be smaller. It would potentially run slower on an armv7s processor than the same binary optimized for armv7s. How much slower depends on the nature of the code and how much it lends itself towards armv7s optimization.