# iPhone/iPod Touch error uploading application to app store

Tags: ios, upload, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS 6 Xcode 4.5 unsupported architecture armv7s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832232/ios-6-xcode-4-5-unsupported-architecture-armv7s)

I'm going to upload my application to app store, but when I'm sending it, I get this message:

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQMwh.png

Somebody know what this is? Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go on project properties.

Select your target
Click on Build Settings
On Architectures, double click on Valid Architectures. Then remove armv7s, leave only armv7.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be using an old version of a library.  I would recommend checking what libraries you are using, and get the latest version. The ARMv7s instruction set is used in the new iPhone 5 processor (A6) and I believe the 5th gen iPod Touch.  Check the Architecture setting in your project to make sure it is set appropriately.